# Microsoft HPC pack / MPI , scheduler not regrowing task in job?

Tags: cloud, mpi, cluster-computing, scheduling, hpc

I have Job that is composed by three tasks:

- Task 1 : min 1, max 4 nodes
- Task 2 : min 1, max 1 node
- Task 3 : min 1, max 4 nodes

My scheduler is set up as Queued, graceful preemption and with adjust resources automatically. Jobs are scheduled via a service on a target machine, all with the same priority.

Here is my question: even with one job queued, sometimes, the scheduler allocates only one node to Task 3, even if there are no other jobs queued. Is this working as intended? By trial and error i can see that if task 1 + 2 doesn't take much time, then task3 will have 4 nodes allocated. Otherwise, if task1+2 takes a little longer (20 mins or so) then task3 always gets allocated 1 node only.

I'm not sure if this is working as intended or if i should write some kind of service that periodically checks the queue status and if needs be, changes the task3 minimum nodes requirement before task2 finishes its course of action.

Any insight is appreciated, thanks!